# why scipy poisson do not have a pdf (probability density function) method?

Tags: python, scipy, poisson

I want to plot the probability density function of a Poisson distribution in python created using scipy.
If I want to plot the pdf of a beta distribution, I would do something like the following:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 200)
alphas = 4
betas = 10
pdf = st.beta.pdf(x, alpha, beta)
plt.plot(x, pdf, label=r'$\alpha$ = {}, $\beta$ = {}'.format(alpha, beta))
```

I thought I could do the same with a Poisson distribution, but unfortunately, the object does not have the `pdf` method! why? how can I plot a Poisson pdf without writing the formula myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The poisson distribution is a discrete distribution and does not have a density function. It however has a mass function, which you can access using scipy.stats.poisson.pmf().

Comment: Correct, however, it does not behave as you would expect. If you use poisson.pmf in place of beta.pdf, the graph is  wrong, and the values are all close to zero. How would I plot that?

Comment: @DarioB: `poisson.pmf(np.arange(5), mu=1) ` returns `array([0.36787944, 0.36787944, 0.18393972, 0.06131324, 0.01532831])`, which agrees with the plot labeled λ = 1 on the [wikipedia page on the Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).  Be sure you only pass in integers as the first argument to the pmf function.

Comment: Yes, the passed values needs to be integers, The function do not takes non discrete values. Thanks!